# Is there a way so that i can have two actions on one form?

Tags: php, html, web

This is what I currently have:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

as you can see the form is already occupied by one action, however, I would also like it to direct to another URL and I don't if something like this would be possible. Unless there's another way where you can redirect to another webpage, that could work too

Comment: What you can do is that when you are done in the first `URL`, redirect to the second `URL` from the first `URL`

Comment: Validate your data after submission and have the server redirect you to the page of your choice.

Comment: on first page end use header('Location:second_page.php');

Comment: you can use jquery for this